# How can I list all folders by name programatically using the fd-find crate?

Tags: rust

I want to list all folders named "test" when in my application using [fd-find](https://crates.io/crates/fd-find).

The documentation shows how to call it in the terminal but doesn't tell how to call it from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the look of it fd-find is not shipped as a library so I guess your best bet would be something like [std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html).